# onKeyDown not getting called when a dialog is up

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have dialog with a custom view that I popup when a list item is clicked. I override the `onKeyDown` function of my activity to see if a dialog was up when the back button was pressed but if the dialog is up the `onKeyDown` does not get called.

If I hit the back button after the dialog is gone it gets called no problem but I need to know if the back button was hit while a dialog was up to handle if I need to re-pop it up if the device rotated.

I searched a bit and it appears that it has something to do with calling `setContentView` for my custom dialog layout but what I did not find is how to get the `okKeydown` to work with that dialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Dialogs we have separate setOnKeyListener so Try below code and.......
and you can track any key press like i did...

- keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA
- keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH
  etc.

  ```
        mProgressDialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {

              @Override
              public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                  if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA)) {
                      return true;
                  }
                  if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH)) {
                      return true;
                  }
                  return false;
              }
          });
  ```